# Trying to generate a spreadsheet of .yaml files within a folder including args

Tags: linux, text-processing, yaml

I have a folder full of .yaml files. in each yaml file i have a url arg among other things. im just trying to get a spreadsheet that has the name of the file in the first column and have the value of the url arg in the second column. is there a simple console command that can do this?

in the yaml file it looks essentially like this

args:

- {arg: file_name, value: "testfile"}

- {arg: url, value: "fakesite.com"}

the goal is to have a spreadsheet were those two values are listed side by side for each yaml file in the folder.

Comment: Can you show a representative example of the yaml file?

Comment: would a CSV output be acceptable? (Unix filenames can contain almost any character, so it can be tricky to carefully represent them)

Comment: Why does the sample input look more like JSON than YAML?

Comment: @JeffSchaller actually YAML does support this JSON-like syntax for inlined arrays

Comment: @Teddy What do you mean by "*simple* command"? Something like `yaml2csv my_file.yml`? Unlessyou make it a standalone command you would end up using `awk`, `sed` and co...

Comment: I see you have a file_name `arg` in the example; should the output contain that value, or the filename on disk?

Comment: BTW, don't forget to register your account and to take our [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), which is YAML-wrapper for `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

For one file:

```
res=$(echo 'args:

- {arg: file_name, value: "testfile"}

- {arg: url, value: "fakesite.com"}' | egrep "file|url")
echo $res
- {arg: file_name, value: "testfile"} - {arg: url, value: "fakesite.com"}
```

You might need to narrow the grep pattern, to reduce false positives:

```
egrep -- "- \{arg: (file_name|url), value: ")
```

So collecting the filenames could be done with find, or with a flat directory just with a for loop. You don't have blanks in filenames or funky characters?

```
for f in *.yaml; do res=$(egrep -- "- \{arg: (file_name|url), value: " $f); echo $res; done > yaml.csv 
cat yaml.csv 
- {arg: file_name, value: "testfile"} - {arg: url, value: "fakesite.com"}
- {arg: file_name, value: "testfile"} - {arg: url, value: "fakesite.com"}
```

Or better readable

```
for f in *.yaml
do 
  res=$(egrep -- "- \{arg: (file_name|url), value: " $f)
  echo $res
done > yaml.csv
```

From there, it should just be a step.